# Excel formula look up

Tags: excel, formula

I have a list of names in cell C2:C50, some of which occur multiple times. I want to insert a formula in cell C51 which will look in the cells above and pull the name whose last occurance was the earliest (so row 51 - row of last occurance of that name)

I wrote this formula

=INDEX($C$2:C50, MATCH(MIN(IF(COUNTIF($C$2:C50, $C$2:C50)=1, ROW($C$2:C50))), ROW($C$2:C50), 0))

This works for the most part where names occur only once in the list. But returns an N?A where name occurs multiple times

Comment: actually managed to resolve this

=INDEX($C$2:C25,MIN(XMATCH($O$6:$O$18,$C$2:C25,0,-1),100),0)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Copy this formula `=COUNTIF(C2:$C$50,C2)` in cell D2 an drag it down, the first number 1 occurrence is the name that you looking for. so you can use index and match functions o extract the name.

```
=INDEX(C2:C50,MATCH(1,D2:D50,0))
```